# column formatter for JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, tabulator

Im trying to use Tabulator and having and issue finding the correct formatter to show JSON objects.
if I pass it as a JSON the cell displays [Object, Object] and if I stringify it before I get it as a long text ( textarea )
is there any built in formatter for JSON datatype? is there a way around it to display the data as a JSON object.
Thank you

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(data,null,4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the suggestion by Nilesh, you would need to create a formatter that implements the `JSON.stringify` function and parts of the built in *textarea* formatter:

```js
function jsonFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    cell.getElement().style.whiteSpace = "pre-wrap"; //allow cell to take up multiple lines of text

    return JSON.stringify(cell.getValue(),null,4); //return JSON formatted cell
}
```

When you then attach the formatter to a column in the column definition, you will also need to set the `variableHeight` option to `true` to tell Tabulator that this cell can change height based on its contents, this is needed to ensure the cell is drawn correctly when the table/column is resized

```js
{title:"Example", field:"example", formatter:jsonFormatter, variableHeight:true}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
This actually starts to resolve the issue for me. 
Is it possible to replace or fill the cell element with HTML ? ( react/svelte components ) or does the formatter only return data values

Comment: If you want to pass html directly into a cell from its value you can use the built it 'html' formatter

Comment: You can also return Dom node from the formatter and it will.add that to the cell